# How can I get Google to re-crawl my site's description?

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics, google-search-console, google-search

When I first submitted my website to Google my website's robots.txt had disallowed the search engines from fetching the URL and so whenever I enter my websites domain to check on google the description shows as "A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt". But now I modified my robots.txt file to allow search engines to crawl the website. How can I force google to re-crawl my website's description?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need Google to recrawl the pages](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52757/need-google-to-recrawl-the-pages)

Comment: It will happen in time. However, if your site is not too large, you can always do a Fetch as Google and Submit to Index in Google Search Console. It will take a couple of days to update - it is not immediate. You can do quite a few pages each day. I do not suggest submitting all of your pages unless your site is small, however, I do suggest you submit your most important pages plus a few. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Use the *[Submit to Index](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch)* function of the *Fetch as* Google tool to re-crawl your URLs

> Ask Google to crawl and index your URL
>
> Click Submit to Index, shown next the status of a recent, successful fetch in the Fetches Table.
>
> Select Crawl only this URL to submit one individual URL to the Google for re-crawling. You can submit up to 500 individual URLs in
>   this way within a 30 day period.
>
> Select Crawl this URL and its direct links to submit the URL as well as all the other pages that URL links to for re-crawling. You can
>   submit up to 10 of requests of this kind within a 30 day period.
>
> Click Submit to let Google know that your request is ready to be processed.