# Best Ways to get Google to Re-index existing and new pages

Tags: search-engine-indexing, fetch-as-google

I know that this has been partially answered previously.  But I am curious what the best and available ways to have Google reindex pages.

If it is just one page that you changed - title, meta description, content, and you want Google to reindex, do you use Search Console and Fetch as Google?  And if so, do you recommend Fetch, or Fetch and Render - and what is the difference?

If you made lots of changes to many pages, do you simply Fetch (or Fetch and Render) the entire site and how do you do that?  The info says to leave the URL blank to fetch the home page, but what if there are many pages you changed?

OR what about the Search Console submit a URL? 
 How is that different or better than Fetch?
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?pli=1

Any help or guidance is apprecaited.

We made changes to the Titles and Descriptions of many pages and some ARE indexed whilst some are not.

Comment: You don't need to do anything.  Just wait a couple weeks.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, for taking the time to comment.  By saying you don't need to do anything, IF you do what the others say below, won't it help?

Comment: Submitting to Google Search Console via fetch as Google, will make Google come crawl a page immediately but it is a manual process and you can only do it for a limited number of pages.  There is no real need to do it, Googlebot automatically recrawls all pages regularly.

Comment: As for why some pages don't get indexed, see: [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login to Google [Search Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en).

Go to `Crawl` > `Fetch as Google` > `Enter URL` > `Fetch and Render`.

Wait a little while. A loading indicator will appear in the list below under the Status column. When the status changes, a button should appear in its place. It will either say "Partial" or "Complete" (there may be other statuses I haven't seen before). You should see a button to the right of that status that says "`Request Indexing`".

Click `Request Indexing`.

To address the second part of your question, When you click Request Indexing (after you've clicked Fetch and Render), Google will present you with 2 options:

1. Index only the URL you entered;
2. Index the URL and all pages it directly links to.

Choose the second option if that suits you best. For example, you could enter your homepage URL, and if it directly links to all of the pages you want Google to re-index, then that second option is the one you should be using.

Sometimes it takes time for all of your pages to be indexed by Google. Google might even decide not to index every page on your site.

For example, I requested my entire site to be indexed. But only 496 out of 562 pages were indexed. *However*, several weeks later I began to notice (without any changes by me) that more pages were still being indexed. As to the "why" of your question, well, we need a lot more info from you to determine why not all of your pages were indexed. There are a lot of variables to consider.

Comment: So if a page in the website is NOT linked to the home page, it will not be re-indexed in your opinion?  Or is using the home page like saying the entire site?

Comment: @BryanBloom Some of your pages pay still be re-indexed at some point in time if you choose not to re-index linked pages, however I don't believe it will be a result of this particular re-indexing - it will be a part of their normal re-index schedule, whenever that may be.

Comment: @BryanBloom If you select the homepage (base URL), _and_ select `Crawl this URL and its direct links`, then, yes, it's _like_ saying _the entire site_. It may not go as deep as you'd like though. I guess a good way to think about it is if there is a link on that homepage, it will be re-indexed.

Comment: The Google Search Console interface changed quite a bit this year. Care to update your answer with how to get Google to index your page(s) in light of these changes Jay?

Answer (score 1):

There are various method to tell Google to reindex your old page. You can submit it in Google Search Console as Jason Pezzimenti indicated above, or you can update your sitemap's last modification date and resubmit it. Whenever Google arrives at your sitemap.xml file, it will crawl all your updated and newly added pages.

Have a look to this Moz article, it will help you: [How to generate sitemap.xml file](https://moz.com/blog/xml-sitemaps-guidelines-on-their-use)

Comment: Thank you so very much.. I didn't know this - about updating date on sitemap.  So nice to learn from you and others.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much! BTW that moz article is 10 years old and is still so relevant!  Never knew about the additional items you can add to the sitemap.

Comment: Google has said they pretty much ignore the last updated date and change frequency fields in sitemaps because so many sites don't use them appropriately.   This method won't work.